# delay between my function and the redirection to a route

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

I'm working on a page in nodeJs with express which return me a table. I have an error about my variable "allMusique" containing my data on my page when I try to access it but after I reload once, the page shows up correctly with my data. Does someone see what is wrong please?

Here is my code:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";
var allMusique;
var idMaxMusique;

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    function getAllMusique(){
        MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
            if (err) throw err;
            var dbo = db.db("projet_node");
            dbo.collection("musiques").find({}).toArray(function(err, result) {
                if (err) throw err;
                allMusique = result;
                var size = allMusique.length-1;
                idMaxMusique = parseInt(result[size].id)+1;
            });
        });
    }

    getAllMusique();
    res.render('musiques', { resultat: allMusique, idMax: idMaxMusique });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: async has made another victim. please check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Comment: Read about [async/await and promises with MongoDB](https://medium.com/@rossbulat/using-promises-async-await-with-mongodb-613ed8243900)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First time you call res.render the variable allMusique is not set yet, because it didn't wait for the database access to finish, on the second try it's already written because of the first access.

I recommend calling res.render inside of the Mongoclient.connect

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
        if (err) throw err;
        var dbo = db.db("projet_node");
        dbo.collection("musiques").find({}).toArray(function(err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            allMusique = result;
            var size = allMusique.length-1;
            idMaxMusique = parseInt(result[size].id)+1;
            res.render('musiques', { resultat: allMusique, idMax: idMaxMusique });
        });
    });
});
```

if you really want to preserver the structure you can make the res.render into a function callback

```
function getAllMusique(callbackFunction){
    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
        if (err) throw err;
        var dbo = db.db("projet_node");
        dbo.collection("musiques").find({}).toArray(function(err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            allMusique = result;
            var size = allMusique.length-1;
            idMaxMusique = parseInt(result[size].id)+1;
            callbackFunction();
        });
    });
}

getAllMusique(()=>res.render('musiques', { resultat: allMusique, idMax: idMaxMusique }));
```

or make the functon return a promise when the value has been already written

```
function getAllMusique(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
            if (err) throw err;
            var dbo = db.db("projet_node");
            dbo.collection("musiques").find({}).toArray(function(err, result) {
                if (err) throw err;
                allMusique = result;
                var size = allMusique.length-1;
                idMaxMusique = parseInt(result[size].id)+1;
                resolve();
            });
        });
    });
}

getAllMusique().then(()=>res.render('musiques', { resultat: allMusique, idMax: idMaxMusique }));
```

Answer (score 0):

`getAllMusique` is an async function. You just need to move the render into the callback

Answer (score 0):

One of the solutions is also using async/await.

```
router.get('/', async function(req, res, next) {

//...

await getAllMusique();
res.render('musiques', { resultat: allMusique, idMax: idMaxMusique });

}
```

Note that callback in `.get()` is now `async` and that allows you to `await` your function.